# Getting prime numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list  `lst = [121, 4, 37, 441, 7, 16]` , I would like to remove from it all numbers that repeat themselves, resulting in a new string that would be `lst = [37,7]` (the prime numbers of the original string).

So far I'd only managed to put out this code:

```
def func(lst,x):
    y = []
    for i in lst:
        for x in range (1, i):
            if (i % x) == 0 :
                y.append(i)
    return y

print(func(lst,3))
```

Instead of getting `lst = [37,7]`, I'm getting this weird looking list:

```
[121, 121, 4, 4, 37, 441, 441, 441, 441, 441, 441, 441, 441, 7, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

Is there any way I can make this work ?

Comment: `121%1 == 0` is of course true, as is `121%11 == 0`. Your code repeats each number `k` times, where `k` is the number of proper divisors (including `1`). Since this seems to be homework, I'll let you puzzle out how to fix it.

Comment: I don't get? You want to remove all non-prime numbers ?

Comment: Thank you John Coleman, I sure will!

Answer (score 2):

As this feels like a homework question, I won't give working code, but a strategy.  You want to ensure that only the numbers of the original list remain, or filter out the numbers that are not prime.

Slightly more formally, "for each number in the list, determine if it's prime, and if so, include it in a new list".

Your code is 90% there, but your kernel (the primality test) is not correct.  The key to testing primality is to ensure that each possible integer divisor does *not* evenly divide the number in question.

For example, if testing 6, the list of possible "0 remainder" integer divisors is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The first and last numbers (1 and 6) don't mean anything as far as primality (6/1 is 6, and 6/6 is 1).  So, your list of possible divisors to test is now

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

From here, I think an insight you're missing in your code is that *for a number to be prime, **all** of its possible divisors must not produce an even number (i.e., remainder of 0)*.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you hunteke. Didn't want the solution anyway, otherwise I don't learn! I will post here the right code once I've found it!

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt

def func(n)
    list1=[]
    list2=[]

    for z in (all(i % x for x in range(2,int(sqrt(i)+1))) for i in n):
        list1.append(z)

    for i,j in enumerate(list1):
        if j == True:
            list2.append(n[i])
return list2
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't too helpful. Please explain why it works.